# How to fire INotifyPropertyChanged on a read-only property that uses nested properties to calculate a value

Tags: c#, wpf, binding, datagrid, inotifypropertychanged

My questions is similar to this [INotifyPropertyChanged and calculated property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2235890/inotifypropertychanged-and-calculated-property)

I'm reusing some code from the above example because it's easier to understand what's going on.

Assume I started with something similar to this. Note that INotifyPropertyChangedBase is the base class that I use to implement INotifyPropertyChanged.

```
public class Order : INotifyPropertyChangedBase
{
  private string itemName;
  public string ItemName 
  { 
    get { return itemName; }
    set 
    {
       itemName = value;
    }
  }

  private decimal itemPrice;
  public decimal ItemPrice 
  { 
    get { return itemPrice; }
    set 
    {
       itemPrice = value;
    }
  }

  private int quantity;
  public int Quantity 
  { 
    get { return quantity; }
    set 
    {
       quantity= value;
       OnPropertyChanged("Quantity");
       OnPropertyChanged("TotalPrice");
    }
  }

  public decimal TotalPrice
  {
    get { return ItemPrice * Quantity; }    
  }
}
```

After generating similar code to this I realized that each order could be comprised of multiple `Items` so I generated a `class : Item` similar to this:

```
public class Item : INotifyPropertyChangedBase
{
  private string name;
  public string Name
  {
    get { return name; }
    set { name = value; }
  }

  private decimal price;
  public decimal Price
  {
    get { return price; }
    set { price = value; }
  }

  private int quantity;
  public int Quantity
  {
    get { return quantity; }
    set
    { 
      quantity = value;
      OnPropertyChanged("Quantity");
    }
  }
}
```

Then I converted my `Order` class to look like this.

```
public class Order : INotifyPropertyChangedBase
{
  private ObservableCollection<Item> itemInfo;
  public ObservableCollection<Item> ItemInfo 
  { 
    get { return itemInfo; }
    set 
    {
       itemInfo = value;
       OnPropertyChanged("ItemInfo");
       OnPropertyChanged("TotalPrice");
    }
  }

  public decimal TotalPrice
  {
    get 
    { 
      Decimal totalPrice;
      foreach (Item item in ItemInfo)
      {
        totalPrice += item.Quantity * item.Price;
      }
      return totalPrice;
    }    
  }
}
```

Implementing this is done via a `DataGrid`. Each `Order` is a row. I am binding column headers to `Item.Name` (limited number of options) and `Item.Quantity` to the appropriate column cell. The final column is the `TotalPrice`.

Previously, the `TotalPrice` would update when I changed the `Quantity`. Now, with the new implementation using `Item` the `TotalPrice` will not update in the `DataGrid`. It seems that the setter for `ItemInfo` will not fire when I update a instance of `Item.Quantity`. The setter on `Item.Quantity` does fire when I update the appropriate `DataGrid` cell.

How do I get the value of a read-only property (`TotalPrice`) to update using nested properties (`Item`)?

Comment: Hook the PropertyChanged event for each item you going to add in ItemInfo.  Like item1.PropertyChanged += item_PropertyChanged. In that item_PropertyChanged handler check e.PropertyName=="Quantity" and Raise OnPropertyChanged("TotalPrice"); inside that condition check.

Comment: Can you provide a bit more detail. Possibly putting this in an answer? I'm having trouble implementing the potential solution below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will have to listen CollectionChanged of ItemInfo like

```
public class Order : INotifyPropertyChangedBase
{
   public Order()
   {  
    ItemInfo =new ObservableCollection<Item>();
    ItemInfo.CollectionChanged += ItemInfo_CollectionChanged;

    }

void ItemInfo_CollectionChanged(object sender, System.Collections.Specialized.NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        OnPropertyChanged("TotalPrice");
    }

   private ObservableCollection<Item> itemInfo;
   public ObservableCollection<Item> ItemInfo 
   { 
     get { return itemInfo; }
     set 
     {
         itemInfo = value;
         OnPropertyChanged("ItemInfo");
         OnPropertyChanged("TotalPrice");
}
```

}

> OR

```
public class Order : INotifyPropertyChangedBase
{

void ItemInfo_CollectionChanged(object sender, System.Collections.Specialized.NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        OnPropertyChanged("TotalPrice");
    }

   private ObservableCollection<Item> itemInfo;
   public ObservableCollection<Item> ItemInfo 
   { 
     get { return itemInfo; }
     set 
     {
         if(itemInfo!=null)
             itemInfo.CollectionChanged -= ItemInfo_CollectionChanged;

         itemInfo = value;

         if(itemInfo!=null)
             itemInfo.CollectionChanged += ItemInfo_CollectionChanged;

         OnPropertyChanged("ItemInfo");
         OnPropertyChanged("TotalPrice");
}
```

}

Comment: I'm going to try implementing this. Just to stir the pot a little, if I were to use for example: 2 explicit instances of `Item` class in the `Order`class would I then subscribe each individual `Item` to the same `ChangedEvent`?

Comment: Thats the magic of ObservableCollection. Whenever you will make any change in Item of this collection It will Notify

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't that clear. I was suggesting, instead of using an ObservableCollection I would use explicit instances of Item.

Comment: Also, I just noticed that you unsubscribe from the event first. Why is that?

Comment: I do it this way unsubscribe the event before subscribing it . It is like when you will assign new value to ItemInfo it firstly unsubscribe the event from previous list.